# "incompatible types: unexpected return value" when my method isnt void and has a return

Tags: java, methods, types, return

I'm trying to do an assignment for my into to java class where this method reads an array of objects from a text file and returns them, but I am running into an incompatible types: unexpected return value error on this method:

```
public readContacts(String fileName){
    Contact[] fileContents;
    try(ObjectInputStream fileIn = new ObjectInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(fileName)))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            fileContents = (Contact[]) fileIn.readObject();
            return fileContents;
        }
    }
    catch (EOFException e)
    {}
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
}
```

Every other question with this error that I saw, someone put the method as void put still entered a return value. Obviously this does not apply in my case.

Comment: for a start put a return type to your method declaration:
public Array<Contact> readContacts(String fileName){...}

Answer (score 0):

you did not specify the data type of your function.

```
Contact [] readContacts(String fileName) {}
```